# How does "Power over Factorial" imply convergence of $e^x$?

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

I was going through the following proof of the fact that $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty x^n/n! = \lim_{n\to\infty}(1 + x/n)^n$ at [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Real_Exponential_Function/Limit_of_Sequence_implies_Power_Series_Expansion):

[image]

The [Power over Factorial](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Power_over_Factorial) entry states that $x^n/n!\to 0$ for any real $x$.

However, I am at loss on how this helps in concluding that
$$
1 + x + \left( \frac{n - 1}{n} \right)\frac{x^2}{2!} + \cdots
$$
goes to the claimed limit $1 + x + x^2/2! + \cdots$.

Any help?

Comment: See [Tannery's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem) with the example of the exponential function. It uses the knowledge of the power series that you want to prove here, but that part can be replaced by a reference to the series being convergent.

Comment: @Gary 's comment is actually the answer

Comment: Do you have trouble computing the limit of $\frac{n-1}n$ etc?

Comment: @Gary Thanks! I had never heard of Tannery before. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.